# Using p4 client to exclude files: "Client xxxx not changed"

Tags: command-line, perforce, perforce-client-spec

So I just set up a Perforce depot and I'm working with a Unity project. Unity has a guid mapper that generates hashes for every file in the project specific to that user's machine. These files have to be excluded; if they are checked out by another user, that user's project will be irreparably corrupted.

I've read that the canonical way to do this is with mappings in the View portion of a client spec. I'm using this command:

p4 client -S //depot/main ssedlmayr_Pearl_Placenta

This is what my client spec looks like:

---

Client: ssedlmayr_Pearl_Placenta

Update: 2013/10/04 19:47:56

Access: 2013/10/04 21:56:14

Owner:  ssedlmayr

Host:   placenta.main

Description:
    Created by ssedlmayr.

Root:   F:\1_Projects\Lighthaus\Placenta.P4V(4)\ssedlmayr_Pearl_Placenta

Options:    noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir

SubmitOptions:  submitunchanged

LineEnd:    local

Stream: //depot/main

View:
    //depot/main/... //ssedlmayr_Pearl_Placenta/...

---

At the bottom there I'm trying to add this mapping to exclude the /metadata/ folder:

```
    -//depot/main/ssedlmayr_Pearl_Placenta/code/UnityProject/Library/metadata/... //ssedlmayr_Pearl_Placenta/code/UnityProject/Library/metadata/...
```

...however when I close the file to upload the new spec to the server, the response is:

"Client ssedlmayr_Pearl_Placenta not changed."

Then when I run the p4 client command again, the spec loads up without the exclusion.

I'm running 64 bit Windows 7 Ultimate. I've tried, but I can't really find any documentation about this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

When using a Streams client, you can't really use the View: field yourself, as with Streams, the server manages the View: data and ignores your attempts to set the View:

Can you use the P4IGNORE functionality to exclude these files? Here's some docs: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/env.P4IGNORE.html